# Can't use Signature Scheme v1, v2 simultaneously

Tags: android, apk

I'm trying to generate a signed apk from my project in Android Studio but APK Signature Scheme v1 doesn't seem to work when enabling both Signature Scheme v1 and v2, v1 seems to get invalidated, `apksigner -verify -v` returns:

```
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): false
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false
Number of signers: 1
```

Using either v1 or v2 on their own is shown to validate. As far as I have read using both, however, is the best approach.

Comment: Use the GUI mode of android studio to create a signed apk with both v1 and v2 signatures enabled in the checkbox.

Comment: I did using Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK > Ticked both boxes.

Comment: Did that created the signed apk then? Using both as checked?

Comment: The apk was created, however, only v2 was verified when checking this apk.

Comment: I am seeing same issue. That v1 is not showing as signed even though I tick both boxes. I even added v1SigningEnabled to my release signingConfig and am not seeing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I encounter this issue, it's due to not providing a low-enough minimum API level. You need at least Android 6 or lower (API level 23), I'm assuming you are using a minimum API level of 24 or greater. v1 jar signature schema will be false if you don't support API level 23 or lower.

I ran into this supporting a 3rd party app store, not play store that required this.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Is there any way to force a v1 signing without changing the API level?